# Possible to switch out a value that's being returned in an if/else method?

Tags: c#

I have the following code in a `Calculations.cs` class:

```
public decimal decPaymentPlan(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        if (quoteData.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlanRadioButton 
            == StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No)
            return PriceQuote.priceNoPaymentPlan;
        else
            return PriceQuote.pricePaymentPlanChapter7; //may want to switch
                                                        //to Chapter13 value
    }

public decimal CalculateChapter7(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        decimal total = PriceQuote.priceChapter7;
        total += this.decPaymentPlan(quoteData); //want to be able to tell
                                                 //which to use, 7 or 13
        return total;
    }
```

I am trying to see if I can avoid an extra `decPaymentPlan` where the final return is `pricePaymentPlanChapter13`. I thought there might be a way to switch it out.

Otherwise, I'd have to do the following:

```
public decimal decPaymentPlanChapter7(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        ...
        else
            return PriceQuote.pricePaymentPlanChapter7;
    }

public decimal decPaymentPlanChapter13(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        ...
        else
            return PriceQuote.pricePaymentPlanChapter13;
    }

...

//the following will appear anyway, but rather than just using
//one method call which switches the choice based on something
public decimal CalculateChpater7(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        ...
        //instead of decPaymentPlan(quoteData) + something to switch
        total+= this.decPaymentPlanChapter7(quoteData);
        ...
    }

public decimal CalculateChpater13(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        ...
        //instead of decPaymentPlan(quoteData) + something to switch
        total+= this.decPaymentPlanChapter13(quoteData);
        ...
    }
```

Is something like this doable (and how)? Thanks. Appreciate any code samples or guidance.

**UPDATE:**
This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult EMailQuote()
{
    Calculations calc = new Calculations();

    QuoteData quoteData = new QuoteData
    {
        StepFilingInformation = new Models.StepFilingInformation
        {
            //just moking user input here temporarily to test out the UI
            PaymentPlanRadioButton = Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes,
        }
     };

     var total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData);
     ViewBag.CalculatePrice = total; // ADDED THIS LINE
     return View(quoteData);
}
```

Also, I set a value in PriceQuote for Chapter7 and Chapter 13 (e.g., `public static decimal priceChapter7 { get { return 799; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to be sure of a suggestion without understanding more about what you are doing, but if the only difference between your methods are a set of values to use (one set for chapter7, the other for chapter13) it may make sense to take these values out of PriceQuote and create a base type to hold these values.  Then your decPaymentPlan and other methods would only take an instance of that type.  For example:

```
class Chapter // for lack of a better name
{
    public decimal PaymentPlan { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Then, change your methods to take a Chapter parameter

```
public decimal decPaymentPlan(QuoteData quoteData, Chapter chapter)
{
    if (quoteData.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlanRadioButton 
        == StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No)
        return PriceQuote.priceNoPaymentPlan;
    else
        return chapter.PaymentPlan;
}

public decimal Calculate(QuoteData quoteData, Chapter chapter)
{
    decimal total = chapter.Price;
    total += this.decPaymentPlan(quoteData, chapter);

    return total;
}
```

Now all you would need are two instances of Chapter, one for 7 and the other for 13, and call your calculate method accordingly.

**UPDATE**: To elaborate a bit on what I mean by 'call your calculate method accordingly', lets say for example you had two static variables (somewhere that makes sense in your application, perhaps in Calculations.cs)

```
static Chapter Chapter7 = new Chapter() { Price = 799.99, PaymentPlan = 555.55 };
static Chapter Chapter13 = ...
```

Then in your controller, you would be able to write

```
ViewBag.Chapter7Total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData, Chapter7);
ViewBag.Chapter13Total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData, Chapter13);
```

Comment: When you say call it accordingly, do you mean how I am doing it in the controller? Using @ViewBag to pull it into View. Updated my question with the controller code. Might you be able to elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: How is it you decide whether to calculate the Chapter 7 total or the Chapter 13 total?  By "call it accordingly" I had meant once you decide which chapter to use, call CalculatePrice passing an appropriate Chapter object.

Comment: I'm just using an if/else block in the view, except that if the choice is Unsure, then both values are being passed to two `<td>'s. So, they are both being calculated, just depends on user choice which is shown.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what the problem is.  In any case you want the total for Chapter7 and 13.  Is the issue writing the calculation code cleanly so you Dont Repeat Yourself?  Or is the problem correctly displaying the total in your view.  Your controller code is only saving one total in the ViewBag, so I'm just a little confused about all the moving parts here and what it is you really want.  My answer was specifically to solve the problem of simplifying the total calculation code by extracting the only differences between the two calculations into a separate object.

Comment: Yes, DRY (a bit). I know this isn't optimal code, but I'm trying to clean it up a bit. I can properly calculate totals. I can use both `@ViewBag.CalculateChapter7` or `@ViewBag.CalculateChapter13` (or when "Unsure" both) in a `<td>`. Your proposed solutions seems most on point, and just trying to figure out how I pass the 7 or 13 value into the appropriate method so I stay a bit more DRY. Btw, ty for taking the time.

Comment: I think I understand now, I've updated my answer to include more elaboration.

Comment: That's great. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference between 7 and 13? I would just opt into doing:

```
if (quoteData.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlanRadioButton ==
StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No)              
      return PriceQuote.priceNoPaymentPlan;          
else if (//whatever fulfills ch. 7)             
      return PriceQuote.pricePaymentPlanChapter7;
else //ch. 13
      return PriceQuote.pricePaymentPlanChapter13;
```

Comment: Should have been more clear. The radio button choices are Chapter7/Chapter13/Unsure. I thought to do that, but the Unsure throws a wrench in the idea because of how I am displaying in the view. I've set up two alternatives to the view (a table). In the view I have a condition. If choice is Chapter 7, display that in one `<td>`, if Chapter13, then display that price in that `<td>`. However, if choice is Unsure, then I display BOTH prices in two separate `<td>`'s.

Comment: @REMESQ What's the objection to displaying both prices, then have the user make a decision from there? Saves a lot of work, in my opinion.

Comment: That's a valid point. It's more a personal choice to personalize the view for users that are NOT unsure. Also, this is a basic example of that personalization, in the entire view that choice is used in other manners. Basically, for those that are unsure they get a lot more information, whereas if the user knows what they want they get a more streamlined response.

Comment: Understood. I also see what you are trying to do dynamically with a table. The C# side of things should be fine (display ch. 7, ch. 13, or both). Displaying it is what I think you're more concerned with. Have you thought about using JavaScript to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could create an Enumeration of the `Chapters` and pass that in as a second parameter to the `decPaymentPlan` method yes?

Comment: The radiobutton already uses an `enum` for Chapter7/Chapter13/Unsure. It was in coding that second parameter where I am struggling. Any examples? Thanks.

Comment: The depends on how tightly bound your business logic is to the UI. If you are tightly bound (not good), then you can just query the radio buttons to see if they are checked or not. If you are loosely coupled, then you should have something in the business layer that is tracking the status of the radio button (such as an enumeration).

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your business logic with your visualization layer:

> if (quoteData.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlanRadioButton 
>               == StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No)

A better design would be to have a model on which changes are applied e.g. MVC, MVP, MVVM.

Example:

```
public class View
{
    private Model _model = new Model();

    public View()
    {
    }

    public Controller Controller
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _model.Option = Options.Option1;
    }

    private void OnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (Controller != null)
            Controller.ApplyChanges(_model);
    }
}
```

The controller can then apply business logic free of the view structure, so that you can change either of the two freely.

E.g.

```
public class Controller
{
    Model Model
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    decimal CalculateSum()
    {
        return Model.Items.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
    }
}
```